# Reorder array by values [Codeigniter]

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have a query:

model

```
$query =  $this->db->get();

if($query) {
        return $query->row_array();
} else {
        null;
}
```

view

```
<?php foreach ($funnel as $key => $value): ?>
    ['<?= $key ?>', <?= $value ?>],
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My array result are:

```
['john', 0],
['jane', 113],
['mark', 453],
['philip', 5],
['sofia', 147],
```

How can I reorder my are by values? I already used PHP 'sort()' function but doesn't work with Codeigniter.

```
['mark', 453],
['sofia', 147],
['jane', 113],
['philip', 5],
['john', 0],
```

I want to clarify I don't want reorder directly from query, but I want order from Array.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`row_array()` returns an **Associative** array not a **Multidimensional** array. So your result array look like this.

```
[
   'john' => 0,
   'jane' =>113,
   :
   :
]
```

You can use `arsort()` to order your associative array.

```
<?php foreach (arsort($funnel) as $key => $value): ?>
    ['<?= $key ?>', <?= $value ?>],
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope this helpfull :)